# only show first result of youtube-dl channel request

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to make a script that can view the latest video of a channel, my current method works but it keeps displaying all the videos.

Im wondering if it is possible to only get the first line of this youtube-dl channel request.

Input:

`youtube-dl -i --get-filename -o "%(title)s, %(id)s" "youtube.com/user/pewdiepie/videos"`

Current output:

`WARNING: The url doesn't specify the protocol, trying with http`

`Saying goodbye is hard.., EOWP5Y7eErE`

`This illegal Swedish tradition is insane..., 8ch5LLc1z7s`

`My 12 Things I Can't LiveWithout., 7tB4jwvvuhQ`

`Lot of big changes lately.., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psHriqExm6U`

`Why I deleted the subreddit, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yyjFudHYuw`

`Mr Beast passed me in subs.., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHtqsuA8WJ4`

`Rating Liver Kings Apology, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlNBB0jdL3w`

`'My mom fakes cancer', https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjPIcTU3AAM`

`Twitter Level Predator Exposed, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djr8j-4fS3A`

`Gordon Ramsey vs Fake Italian.., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X98VPQCE_WI`

`Twins wants to be Pregnant (At the same time...), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W27TjYZhytw`

`I Spent 12 Hours at a Japanese Arcade, It was weird. (Collab w_ @PewDiePie ), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIbqhi5Ikq8`

`Dr Phil destroys Gamer boy, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0d-AFtXtkM`

`too big waves for me.., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XR9OzAeDqQ`

`She fell for it!, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzCA5zHayyk`

`Does this mean Im cursed now, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhjjjqmGAkI`

`I took my car off road ... (Oops), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLFJjMokld8`

`^C ERROR: Interrupted by user`

^ Each line for every uploaded video.

Wanted output: `Saying goodbye is hard.., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOWP5Y7eErE`, One line and exited program

(I usually would resolve this just by placing a |head -1 at the end of the command. but the command stays active and my script is paused.)

Version: `2021.12.17`

OS: `debian`

Comment: Please explain this in more detail: *also |head -1 isn't a option bc it has to be quick in my script, I can only use a channel link*

Comment: @Cyrus hope its clear

Comment: @Cyrus I found a fix for the channel ID, 
channelinfo="$(yt-dlp --print channel --print channel_url --playlist-items 1 "youtube.com/user/pewdiepie")";newacc=$(echo "$channelinfo"|tail -1);namesuggest=$(echo "$channelinfo"|head -1|sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"|sed -e "s/ //g")